# How to replace multi-lines of string in a text file by batch script

Tags: string, batch-file, replace, cmd

I need to replace multiple string lines by new values after equal sign

I've already tried with some test data and it's working, issue is that I need to pass full line, but i need to pass part of a line in a text file:
`prop.first.name=firstname`
I need to pass before "=" (or search) and replace firstname by anything else

I did manage to get something working but it's doing for one line... I have at least 4 lines to be executed with the same command

```
CALL :modify prop.first.name , myName
CALL :modify prop.last.name , myLastName
:modify

set "source=srcFile.txt"
set "target=tmpFile.txt"

set property=%~1
set value=%~2

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
(
for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%a in ('findstr /B "^" %source%') do (
  set line=%%b
  if defined line echo !line:%property%=%property%=%value%!
)
) > %target%
 endlocal
```

## source file looks like:

```
prop.first.name=firstname

prop.last.name=lastname

prop.pssw.word=password

prop.url.link=alink
```

## I need to replace value after "=" equal sign to an input

The idea is to call a generic function 4 times with different parameters

Comment: 1. Execution falls into the `:modify` section after the `call` lines since there is no `goto :EOF`. 2. You always replace the text in the *original* file, so you finally get the *last* replacement only...

Comment: With enough effort, you can do this. The tool you really want is `sed` or `awk`, but Windows doesn't come with that. With one of those tools, you would already be done.